# Clipping raster with another raster where selected cell value defined using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.2, clip

Is there where I can clip a raster with another raster by selecting specific cell value defined?

For example, I want to perform the clip operation using raster "A" as input and using raster "X1" as a clip raster where only interested on cell value = 1 in raster "X1". I have time series of rasters i.e. X1, X2, X3 and want to save the clip results with prefix from clip raster.

Is there way to perform this operation using ArcGIS 10.2 and python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with map algebra. Note that "clipping" a raster is not like clipping a vector in the sense that a raster is always a matrix (therefore always rectangular) but you can set values to "NoData"

here is a code sample:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set the current workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "your/workspace"
#loop on all grids in workspace, using wildcard and raster type as option
for eachraster in arcpy.ListRasters("X*", "TIF"):
  outCon = Con(eachraster==1, Raster("A")) #if value of raster "A" equals 1, then use value of "eachraster", else NoData
  outCon.save(eachraster[:-4]+"out.tif")
```